# How do I decide whether I should do a Master Degree or not?

Tags: masters, computer-science

I am a computer science undergrad, graduating in a month's time, with a high-paying job in hand. However, I know that I want to learn and implement new things, explore more domains. I have done several internships and my profile is decent in terms of extra-curricular activities. My GPA is approximately 3.4.

I do not have specific interests as such but space exploration, AI and algorithms fascinate me. I want to know how to decide whether studying for a Masters Degree would be the right thing for me or not.

Comment: It all comes down to what is important to you: e.g. whether you need the income from the high-paying job right now or can afford a couple more years without it, whether you expect higher earnings with a masters degree, and many other highly personal variables that would be impossible to enumerate here.

Comment: You may also want to consider taking the job and continuing your studies on your own. Coursera, for example, has a number of good courses on AI and machine learning, that are on par with my grad level courses in those subjects.

Comment: The MSc takes 1 or 2 years?